# How would I get two files to constantly syncronize

Tags: windows-10

I need to have two files that constantly sync with eachother, so that a change in one of the files will immediatly sync with the other? How can this be done? Can I get SyncToy to be running every few seconds? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don’t know anything that synchronizes on change but Sync Back Pro (I use this) and like can be set to sync very frequently (enough to satisfy demand)

Comment: Do you need two copies, each standalone? (e.g. in two separate filesystems for redundancy). Or will one instance and some kind of link in the other place be enough? What is the filesystem?

Comment: This might not be possible, depending on the editor used. For example, a file opened for editing in MS Word is locked, so that if its mate is changed, the file open in Word *cannot* be modified. Also, if two users are editing the same text, which one's changes take preference? This issue is common in databases, and is called *concurrency*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control and https://www.indicative.com/resource/data-concurrency/  for info.

Comment: what kind of file?  What is the extension?

Comment: Can't something like DropBox do this? [untested, I'm on Mac which can do this type of sync task between all devices natively, no 3rd party required]